# How to update AdMob in existing iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob

My Admod banner isn't displaying when being tested on phone. Xcode tells me its because I have an old version of the sdk. This is the message I'm getting from Xcode:

**You are currently using version 6.12.0 of the SDK, which doesn't officially support iOS 8. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent sdk version, 7.0.0, to get iOS 8 support,**

I downloaded the newest sdk but don't know how to implement it with an existing sdk. Is there anyone that knows how to update admob?

In my current project I have the necessary frameworks and an admod folder that includes GADBannerView.h, GADBannerViewDelegate.h, libGoogleAdMobAds.a,search folder, mediation folder etc...

Thanks

Comment: The sdk version can not be the problem... I m still using the old sdk and everything is working fine. When i run my app connected to XCode, XCode also tells me to update... But this is not a must! I wanted to update but i had problems because they changed a lot and depricated methods and funny as they are there is no documentation for the newest version so i just stayed with the older version and it is still working of course... So if you don t get shown banners it s something with your code and not with your sdk version... That s for sure...

Comment: Yes, you can just ignore this warning (it is from the admob server, not from the compiler) for now, So long as you got to 6.10 or whatever it was when they pulled out the UUID stuff and added the advertiserIdentifier business.  I've stuck with the older in a couple projects too because I still want ios5 support and the new one bottoms out at 6

Answer (score 0):

Admob 6.12.0 still does support iOS8, it is just that they have since done bug fixes - they are now up to 7.1.0 but 6.12.0 should still display ads.

This means that there is something else wrong with your code that is causing the ads not to display. You will need to fix your code. Even in the simulator you should get ads or test ads on 6.12.0 on ios8.